# Pandas .at throwing ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a df where I am extracting one value to store it in another df:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create data set
d = {'foo':[100, 111, 222], 
     'bar':[333, 444, 555]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Full dataframe:
print(df)

# Shows:
#    bar   foo 
# 0  333   100
# 1  444   111
# 2  555   222

df2=pd.DataFrame()
df2.loc[1,'Name'] = df[df.foo == 222]['foo']

#error: 
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

I'm assuming the last line throws that error because `df[df.foo == 222]['foo']` is a `Series`:

```
2    222
Name: foo, dtype: int64
```

So I'm trying to get the value itself. I used `.at` and got this:

```
print(df[df.foo == 222].loc[:,'bar'].at['bar'])

#ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers
```

From what I've read it's `iat` that uses integer indexers and `at` uses both label and integer, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `at` with a boolean mask is considered bad form unless you can 100% guarantee only one row in the mask is true (otherwise, `at` fails).

The best thing to do is to use `loc` and take the first result.

```
df.loc[df.foo == 222, 'bar'].values[0]
555
```

For reference, `at` does not work because returns a single-row Series with a index `[2]`:

```
df[df.foo == 222].loc[:,'bar']

2    555
Name: bar, dtype: int64
```

At this point, `at['bar']` makes no sense because it searches for "bar" in the index and `bar` isn't. What you should've done is

```
df[df.foo == 222].at[2, 'bar']
555
```

Comment: @NathanTew Well, if you think about it; it makes sense. Pandas assumes you know what you are doing when you use these indexer functions, although I will admit there is a non-zero gradient to this learning curve.

Comment: but isn't untrue in itself to say that `at` only can have integer indexers, because it doesn't?

Comment: @NathanTew But `df[df.foo == 222].loc[:,'bar']` _does_ only have integer indices, so it will naturally complain when you try to index with a non-integer (`.at['bar']`).

Comment: @NathanTew (Last ping, promise) Thank you for accepting; you can also upvote the answer if it was helpful. Click the triangle above the "0" to the left of my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the value using `values`

```
df2.loc[1,'Name'] = df[df.foo == 222]['foo'].values
df2

#   Name
# 1 222
```

Comment: thanks, that helped, but my main question was why `.at` isn't working

Comment: pass the complete index to `at` like `at.[row_idx, col_idx]`

Answer (score 0):

The point at which you're using `at`, the data is a Pandas Series with integer Index, That is why your getting the mentioned error.

```
#ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers
```

If you check the index of the data, you'll see an index with value 2

```
df[df.foo == 222].loc[:,'bar'].index

#Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

One of the correct method would be, as mentioned by coldspeed

```
df.loc[df.foo == 222].at[2,'bar']

#555
```

Answer (score 0):

`.at` will work with label indexing, not position indexing.
Example:

```
df.at(3,'ColName')
```

> ## Returns value of `ColName` for 3rd row.